# Unable to install contracting with pip3

Tags: python, mongodb, pip

I'm trying to learn how to build smart contracts in python, but when I try to install contracting from a terminal, I receive this error:

> `C:\Users\Shald\Development\PlayerPayers\Test\my_token\venv>pip3 install contracting
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
> Collecting contracting
> Using cached contracting-1.0.5.2.tar.gz (548 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
> Requirement already satisfied: astor in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from contracting) (0.8.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from contracting) (3.12.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: autopep8 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from contracting) (1.6.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: stdlib_list in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from contracting) (0.8.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: toml in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from autopep8->contracting) (0.10.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle>=2.8.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from autopep8->contracting) (2.8.0)
> Using legacy 'setup.py install' for contracting, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
> Installing collected packages: contracting
> Running setup.py install for contracting ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zepo2kqt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\contracting'
> cwd: C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d
> Complete output (303 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting
> copying contracting\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting
> copying contracting\config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting
> copying contracting_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests
> copying tests\run.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests
> copying tests\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests
> copying tests_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\compilation
> copying contracting\compilation\compiler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\compilation
> copying contracting\compilation\linter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\compilation
> copying contracting\compilation\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\compilation
> copying contracting\compilation\whitelists.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\compilation
> copying contracting\compilation_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\compilation
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\contracts
> copying contracting\contracts\submission.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\contracts
> copying contracting\contracts_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\contracts
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\db
> copying contracting\db\contract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\db
> copying contracting\db\driver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\db
> copying contracting\db\encoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\db
> copying contracting\db\orm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\db
> copying contracting\db_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\db
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution
> copying contracting\execution\executor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution
> copying contracting\execution\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution
> copying contracting\execution\runtime.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution
> copying contracting\execution_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib
> copying contracting\stdlib\env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib
> copying contracting\stdlib_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution\metering
> copying contracting\execution\metering_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution\metering
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\access.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\decimal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\imports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\orm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge\time.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> copying contracting\stdlib\bridge_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\stdlib\bridge
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> copying tests\final_gov\test_add_members.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> copying tests\final_gov\test_foundation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> copying tests\final_gov\test_members.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> copying tests\final_gov\test_rewards.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> copying tests\final_gov\test_stamps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> copying tests\final_gov_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_election_house.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_even_simpler_election_house.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_foundation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_masternodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_master_candidates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_more_flexible_election_house.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_new_candidates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_new_masternodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_pending_masters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_rewards.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_simple_voting_contract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance\test_stamps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> copying tests\governance_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration
> copying tests\integration\test_atomic_swap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration
> copying tests\integration\test_builtins_locked_off.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration
> 3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\tejastokens.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_construct_function_works.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_hashing_works.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_orm_foreign_hash_contract.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_orm_foreign_key_contract.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_orm_hash_contract.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_orm_no_contract_access.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_orm_variable_contract.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_pass_hash.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\test_time.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\thing.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\time_storage.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\precompiled
> copying tests\unit\precompiled\compiled_token.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\precompiled
> copying tests\unit\precompiled\updated_submission.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\precompiled
> copying tests\unit\precompiled_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\precompiled
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\bad_lint.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\compile_this.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\currency.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\good_lint.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module6.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module7.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module8.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts\module_func.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> copying tests\unit\test_sys_contracts_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\test_sys_contracts
> running egg_info
> writing contracting.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to contracting.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing requirements to contracting.egg-info\requires.txt
> writing top-level names to contracting.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'contracting.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> writing manifest file 'contracting.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> copying contracting.gitignore -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting
> copying contracting.version -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting
> copying contracting\execution\metering\tracer.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution\metering
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\nft
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\nft\contracts
> copying tests\nft\contracts\nft.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\nft\contracts
> copying contracting\execution\metering\cu_costs.const -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\contracting\execution\metering
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\currency.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\elect_members.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\election_house.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\foundation.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\members.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\rewards.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> copying tests\final_gov\contracts\stamp_cost.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\final_gov\contracts
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\currency.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\delegates.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\deprecating_masters.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\election_house.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\foundation.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\master_candidates.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\masternodes.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\new_masternodes.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\pending_masters.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\rewards.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\simple_vote.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\stakes.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> copying tests\governance\contracts\stamp_cost.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\governance\contracts
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\builtin_hack_token.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\call_infinate_loop.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\con_inf_writes.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\constructor_infinate_loop.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\double_spend_gas_attack.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\hack_tokens.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\import_hash_from_contract.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\security\contracts\infinate_loop.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\security\contracts
> copying tests\unit\loop_client_test.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\engine
> copying tests\unit\engine\test_cacheDriver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\unit\engine
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\all_in_one.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\dynamic_import.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module1.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module2.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module3.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module4.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module5.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module6.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module7.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> copying tests\integration\test_contracts\modules\module8.s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tests\integration\test_contracts\modules
> running build_ext
> building 'contracting.execution.metering.tracer' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\contracting
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\contracting\execution
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\contracting\execution\metering
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python39\include -Ic:\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um /Tccontracting/execution/metering/tracer.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\contracting/execution/metering/tracer.obj
> tracer.c
> c:\python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\python39\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
> self.spawn(args)
> File "c:\python39\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 507, in spawn
> return super().spawn(cmd)
> File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
> spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
> File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 87, in spawn
> raise DistutilsExecError(
> distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py", line 36, in build_extension
    build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 529, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 403, in compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py", line 45, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py", line 27, in run
    build_ext.run(self)
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "c:\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py", line 38, in build_extension
    raise BuildFailed()
__main__.BuildFailed
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vww8vngq\contracting_b7f1ef37cd7d4f7c928136c5c9e2bd1d\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Shald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zepo2kqt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\contracting' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)`

I'm trying to use Mongo DB. I have a few versions of Python installed, including 3.6.0, but I haven't really used Python before and don't really know what I'm doing. I've received a few different messages while trying to fix this, but this is what it's showing now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file+io.h+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 1):

The Contracting module you are trying to install requires that a c++ compiler is present on the machine.

There are two options for resolving this issue.

Firstly, install Visual C++ Build Tools from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126 and use the default optons.

Or - Following the instructions on the Lamden Consulting docs and install WSL - see the docs here: https://contracting.lamden.io/windows

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to set up, but I've got WSL installed and my environment set up now. That's 1 less problem to deal with.